# Multi Value Results from Nested Query

Tags: soql, php

I have a parent-child nested query like to this:

```
SELECT Name,CloseDate,Theatre,(Select Product__c from Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity  where Name = 'Foo'
```

The result of which, looks like this:

[image]

But I don't want the result nested within the table, I'd like it like this:

[image]

I know this may be down to the normalization of the table, but i don't have control over that in Salesforce, so is there a way to do this from the query or how I am retrieving the result?

I think that's all the relevant information, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Select Product__c , Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.CloseDate, Opportunity.Theatre from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunity.Name = 'Foo'
```

Comment: Simple yet perfect solution! Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of it :)